# SpecFlow tests failing with Access Denied Exceptions

Tags: .net, svn, nunit, orchardcms, specflow

After getting the Orchard CMS up and running then checked into our Subversion repository, I have been looking at the existing test coverage and specifically the SpecFlow tests.

When I try and run the tests from the CodeRush test runner or from NUnit GUI (v2.5.10) I get exceptions on 67 of the tests:

```
Orchard.Specs.AdditionFeature.AnonymousUserCanSeeTheHomePageButNotTheDashboard:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path
'C:\Users\richard.slater\AppData\Local\Temp\Orchard.Specs\5dchvodt.b1i\Modules\
Orchard.Packaging\Views\.svn\all-wcprops' is denied.
```

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
at Orchard.Specs.Util.PathExtensions.FileCopy(Path sourcePath, Path targetPath, Path sourceFile) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Util\PathExtensions.cs:line 51
at Orchard.Specs.Util.PathExtensions.c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Path file) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Util\PathExtensions.cs:line 22
at Bleroy.FluentPath.PathCollection.ForEach(Action`1 action)
at Orchard.Specs.Util.PathExtensions.DeepCopy(Path sourcePath, Path targetPath) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Util\PathExtensions.cs:line 20
at Orchard.Specs.Hosting.WebHost.CopyExtension(String extensionFolder, String extensionName, ExtensionDeploymentOptions deploymentOptions) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Hosting\WebHost.cs:line 202
at Orchard.Specs.Bindings.WebAppHosting.GivenIHaveModule(String moduleName) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Bindings\WebAppHosting.cs:line 132
at Orchard.Specs.Bindings.WebAppHosting.GivenIHaveACleanSiteWith(String virtualDirectory, Table table) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Bindings\WebAppHosting.cs:line 161
at Orchard.Specs.Bindings.OrchardSiteFactory.GivenIHaveInstalledOrchard(String virtualDirectory) in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Bindings\OrchardSiteFactory.cs:line 23
at Orchard.Specs.Bindings.OrchardSiteFactory.GivenIHaveInstalledOrchard() in C:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\Bindings\OrchardSiteFactory.cs:line 16
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.MethodBinding.InvokeAction(Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.ExecuteStep(StepArgs stepArgs)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
at Orchard.Specs.AdditionFeature.AnonymousUserCanSeeTheHomePageButNotTheDashboard() in c:\Project\Damovo.co.uk_NEW\src\Orchard.Specs\PermissionModel.feature:line 28
```

I have tried executing the tests as Administrator, however I have know real knowledge of SpecFlow so I suspect I am missing something critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to access the hidden Subversion folders (.svn) and they are simply not accessible. Possible reasons are:

- **The user accound, under which you are currently operating doesn't have sufficient access rights (read).** Try setting those for the currently logged in user on Security tab on the top-level repository folder Properties' screen - changes should propagate to all lower folders.
- **There is a Subversion client (like TortoiseSVN) running in the background**, which has those files opened for reading/writing. This is more likely. Try turning it off (or killing the SVN client process if there is no option to close it) and see what would happen.

*Messing with internal .svn files can be dangerous and corrupt your checked-out repository folder. I don't know if SpecFlow modifies those files in the process - if not, that's good*

There is also a solution to Export the repository files (*via TortoiseSVN Export option*) to separate folder (*the SVN-related stuff will not be copied*), do all work on the copy, and every time you'd like to commit - copy changed files back to the SVN-bound folder.

Comment: Giving "Everyone" full control over the folder doesn't work. Cloned Orchard from the HG repository and now I get an exception in HttpClient.cs, suspect this is because the tests are expecting to see Orchard on http://localhost/ rather than http://localhost:<port-num>/ I shall investigate further. Thanks for your help and you plugin contributions to the community.